# Using SharedSingleton to attribute value to NSInteger

Tags: ios, xcode

In my viewcontrollerA.h I have:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger showCommentOrCreate;
+ (PhotoViewController *) sharedManager;
```

in viewcontrollerA.m I use:

```
PhotoViewController* sharedSingleton = [PhotoViewController sharedManager];
...(long)sharedSingleton.showCommentOrCreate...

+ (PhotoViewController *)sharedManager
{
static PhotoViewController *shaderManager = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    shaderManager = [[PhotoViewController alloc] init];
});
return shaderManager;
}
```

...to find the value of the integer.

In viewcontrollerB I import ViewcontrollerA.h, and in ViewcontorllerB.m, I attribute a value to showCommentOrCreate.

The only problem is that it seams I have to assign the value to the integer twice for it to change. e.g:

Doesn't work:

```
-(IBAction)addAnImageForCommenting:(id)sender{
PhotoViewController* sharedSingleton = [PhotoViewController sharedManager];
sharedSingleton.showCommentOrCreate = 2;

PhotoViewController* sharedSingleton2 = [PhotoViewController sharedManager];
sharedSingleton2.showCommentOrCreate = 2;

}
```

Doesn't work:

```
-(IBAction)addAnImageForCommenting:(id)sender{

PhotoViewController* sharedSingleton2 = [PhotoViewController sharedManager];
sharedSingleton2.showCommentOrCreate = 2;

}
```

Works:

```
- (void)rightSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {
for (UIImageView *imageView in imageArray)
{

    if (([imageView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && imageView.tag == ((UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer).view.tag))
    {

        // for(UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in [imageView gestureRecognizers]){
        //   if([gesture isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]){

        if (imageView.frame.size.height == 60){

            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.27];
            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            imageView.frame = CGRectMake( 20, imageView.frame.origin.y, 710, 200);
            [UIView commitAnimations];

            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"Massages retina iPad.png"]];

            z = 200;

            for (MKMapView* map in mapViewArray) {
                if (imageView.tag == map.tag +1) {

                    [imageView addSubview:map];

                }
            }

        }else {

            /*[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.27];
            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            imageView.frame = CGRectMake( 20, imageView.frame.origin.y, 710, 60);
            [UIView commitAnimations];

            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"message small.png"]];*/


            z = 60;

            for (MKMapView* map in mapViewArray) {
                if (imageView.tag == map.tag +1) {


                    //[map removeFromSuperview];

                }
            }
        }

    } else if([imageView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && imageView.tag > ((UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer).view.tag){

        if (z == 200){

            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.27];
            imageView.frame = CGRectMake( 20, imageView.frame.origin.y +150, 710, imageView.frame.size.height);
            [UIView commitAnimations];

        }else {
            /*[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.27];
            imageView.frame = CGRectMake( 20, imageView.frame.origin.y -150, 710, imageView.frame.size.height);
            [UIView commitAnimations];*/

        }
    }}




for (UIImageView *imageView in imageArray)
{

    if (([imageView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && imageView.tag == ((UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer).view.tag))
    {

[UIView transitionWithView:imageView duration:0.5
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{
                       //imageView.image = secondImage;
                   } completion:^(BOOL f){

                       UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"PhotoViewControllerStoryboard" bundle:nil];
                       UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
                       vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn;
                       vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
                       [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
                       vc.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(15, 43, 735, 982);

                       PhotoViewController* sharedSingleton = [PhotoViewController sharedManager];
                       sharedSingleton.tagNumber = imageView.tag;
                       //NSLog(@"The tagNumber is: %ld", (long)sharedSingleton.tagNumber);
                       //sharedSingleton.showCommentOrCreate = 1;

                   }];

        PhotoViewController* sharedSingleton = [PhotoViewController sharedManager];
        sharedSingleton.tagNumber = imageView.tag;
        sharedSingleton.showCommentOrCreate = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
}}}
```

As you can see I set the value of the integer twice, and it works, otherwise it doesn't. When It doesn't, if i call the code twice with a time interval, the right value is set. Any ideas??

EDIT: Updated the code I claim to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am so stupid. I'm very sorry. I didn't even realize that i was setting the value in ViewcontrollerB after allocating UIviewcontrollerA, and the call to that value in UIviewcontrollerA is in the view did load.
This fixed it:

```
-(IBAction)addAnImageForCommenting:(id)sender{

PhotoViewController* sharedSingleton = [PhotoViewController sharedManager];
sharedSingleton.showCommentOrCreate = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];

UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"PhotoViewControllerStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn;
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
vc.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(15, 43, 735, 982);

}
```

Instead of...

```
-(IBAction)addAnImageForCommenting:(id)sender{

UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"PhotoViewControllerStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn;
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
vc.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(15, 43, 735, 982);

PhotoViewController* sharedSingleton = [PhotoViewController sharedManager];
sharedSingleton.showCommentOrCreate = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];

}
```

...again i'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from using int's as a primitive variable rather than the NSInteger which is an entire integer class.

To solve this my idea would be to allocate the NSInteger and work with that, but as NSInteger doesn't work that way I'd suggest to go with NSNumber as it behaves entirely as an object

```
 sharedSingleton.showCommentOrCreate = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
```

Comment: ok, I did what you said and when I NSlog the number I get 2013-01-24 19:32:13.702 Splash-it[805:907] num 525683552

Comment: If I put [NSNumber numberWithInt:2]; I get the same value 525683552

Comment: @Alessandro did you change your singleton property from int to NSNumber?

Comment: yes, I did @property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber* showCommentOrCreate;

Comment: ok, using [sharedSingleton.showCommentOrCreate longValue] works, but still the main problem of the question persists

Comment: @perrohunter "`NSInteger` which is an entire integer class." - it isn't. It's just a typedef for `long`.

Comment: @Alessandro Also, what are you trying to achieve exactly? It's quite hard to read the 3rd code snipped what you claim to be working.

Comment: Ok, so basically I want to assign a value from viewcontrollerB and pass it to viewcontrollerA. What I want anything that I can compare with using an if statement in viewcontrollerB, like an NSnumber with 1 and 2, or a Bool with NO or YES.

Comment: I updated my question with the full"3rd code snipped what you claim to be working"