# Assigning NSNumber a value using singleton

Tags: objective-c

I set up my viewcontrollerA as a singleton. In a viewcontrollerA.h I have:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber* showCommentOrCreate;
```

In viewcontrollerB.m I have:

```
PhotoViewController* sharedSingleton = [PhotoViewController sharedManager];
sharedSingleton.showCommentOrCreate = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
```

In my viewcontrollerB.m I have:

```
 PhotoViewController* sharedSingleton = [PhotoViewController sharedManager];
NSLog(@"num %ld", (long)sharedSingleton.showCommentOrCreate);
```

The problem is that for whatever value I set in this way [NSNumber numberWithInt:whole number], I always get a number which isn't the number I have set:

e.g. 2013-01-24 19:42:24.936 Splash-it[870:907] num 475536752

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Why do you think that 1. this is related to Xcode, 2. that the address of (pointer to) the `NSNumber` object should be the same as the value wrapped in it?

Comment: stuff like this works in Java, but not in Obj-C

Comment: @nielsbot: typecasting works even in objective-c. Even in java you can typecast `(ComplexNumber)employeeObject` :p

Comment: You should consider deleting this Question and adding a new one "Strange result printing NSNumber" NSLog(@"%ld",(long)[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]); // prints 475536752, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're printing the pointer to the `NSNumber` object, and not the integer value stored in it.

Comment: please explain, what should I do?

Comment: @Alessandro You should read a good tutorial on C types, with special regards to pointers and primitives.

Comment: @Alessandro Oh or did you mean "plz gimme teh codez"? I see. Use `[sharedSingleton.showCommentOrCreate longValue]` then.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, maybe you can also give me a hand with this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506389/using-sharedsingleton-to-attribute-value-to-nsinteger , but sorry if I don't know as much as you do, thats why you have 40000 of rep. and I 600

Comment: @Alessandro : accept carbonicAcid's answer you will cross 700 :)

Comment: @Alessandro 3 years ago I didn't know much either, yet I didn't have to ask questions like this. Learning from tutorials you have googled and making an effort solves everything.

Comment: @H2CO3 sir and Alessandro : You can see my profile, within 3 months I am 7K even after getting so many downvotes. But my knowledge is not more than 500 in terms of points. Alessandro dont go for points but go for good knowlege one is my peer Mr.Carbonic Acid, H2co3. I think he is not recognizing me, i changed pic and name no.

Comment: @AKV Don't worry, Anoop, I do recognize you :)

Comment: @H2CO3 : I will be only one calling you as CarbonicAcid, isn't it?

Comment: @AKV Well, that's a good question, indeed!

Answer (score 1):

You used %ld with cocoa object.

Convert it into integer/long and use %ld or use %@

Use this :

```
NSLog(@"num %@", sharedSingleton.showCommentOrCreate);
```

Alternatively you can do as :

```
NSLog(@"num %ld", [sharedSingleton.showCommentOrCreate longValue]);

NSLog(@"num %i", [sharedSingleton.showCommentOrCreate integerValue]);
```

Comment: Can I do like this for example: if ((long)sharedSingleton.showCommentOrCreate == 1) {
        
    } ??

Comment: NO.... use [... longValue] or [... intValue]

Comment: @Alessandro ***He just showed you that...*** Please don't be/pretend to be dumb!

Comment: ok, I did [sharedSingleton.showCommentOrCreate longValue] == 1

Comment: @Alessandro That's going to be good.

Comment: aaahhh finally got some consolation :)